# AVPlayer won't play audio despite no errors

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayeritem

In an iOS app of mine, I have a custom audio player class that creates an underlying `AVPlayer` with URL-based audio assets. It's all very vanilla - load an `AVPlayerItem` based on the URL, load the asset data asynchronously, then use it to create an `AVPlayer` instance.

Everything works great, but I just discovered a case where the AVPlayer loads the audio asset and parses it correctly, but refuses to play any audio.

This happens when I have started a couple of games before launching the app. E.g. Minecraft and Monument valley. There is no fail-proof way to reproduce this (sometimes starting Minecraft causes this bug to appear, sometimes not), but if I start a couple of games that use audio, the bug eventually appears.

When I debug the app's current state, the `AVPlayer` has no errors. The status is ready to play etc. etc. Everything looks as it should. The same goes for the `AVPlayerItem`. There is no way for me to make the app play audio...

...unless if I start Spotify and play a song. This fixes any audio locks that may exist and cause my player to not play. If I then leave Spotify and open my app, my audio player can now play audio.

Any ideas what may cause this? I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the answer but you might want to set up AVSession to your audio. [AVSession info](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudiosession) they tell the phone if you audio should be play over others, should stop if a call comes up or if you go to background, etc

It is possible that some of this applications are changing the session of Audio and you are not specifying yours correctly.

I used this code for mine:

```
do {
   try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.interruptSpokenAudioAndMixWithOthers)
   }
 catch {
// report for an error  }
```

This are the category options that worked for me but AVPlayer has different ones, try to see if that helps.

[This are the different Category Options for AVSessions](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudiosessioncategoryoptions)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link, great advice! However, I already do these things. :/

Comment: I am sorry I could not be of more help honestly, I am dealing with a bunch of AVPlayer weird behaviour too. If I find anything or think of an idea I will let you know! good luck :)

Comment: You need to activate the session after setting its type: `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(, with:)` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616627-setactive)).